# Resharper can't detect ContentPlaceHolder ID from master page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages, resharper

I'm very new to ASP.net and webform applications, and I'm inheriting some pretty bad code, but I've got a strange problem that I can't figure out or figure out how to google about it.

In my web site, Resharper is complaining on every page that it couldn't find the corresponding ContentPlaceHolderID from the master page.

Here's a stripped down (for security's sake) version of the ASP.net markup:

```
<%@ page language="VB" masterpagefile="~/_site.master" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="MyWebPage" theme="Base" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
  <h1>SomeText</h1>
  <br />
</asp:Content>
```

And here's the _site.master file (located at the root of the web site):

```
<%@ master language="VB" inherits="_CompanyName" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title>SomeTitle</title>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      ....form stuff
    </form>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ContentPlaceHolder"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </body>
</html>
```

Almost every page displays this error. Here's the literal Resharper error message: "Cannot resolve symbol 'ContentPlaceHolder'.

Any ideas? Any way I can have Resharper stop displaying this error message? It doesn't effect the actual rendering of the page at all (as far as I know), because the page displays correctly according to the original makers. I'm just trying to get Resharper to play nicely.

Comment: This usually means a compilation error somewhere, probably in the aspx/ascx (not the .cs file).  If you add a deployment project, then make the site not-updatable, that will do a complete compile often revealing compilation errors that you otherwise would have to visit each page to see.

Comment: So I get this straight, you're saying that the master file may have compilation issues? I'm not sure that it does. It's been used on these deployed websites for years, and I haven't heard anything erroneous about them. Also, these sites are build to allow plugins and such to allow programmers to change the website pages. Does that have anything to do with your mention of "not_updatable"? Sorry, I'm really rather new.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem - whereas the whole solution compiles fine. Is it eventually a (known) bug in ReSharper?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can now.

Install a newer version of ReSharper (**6.1** or later) and try it again.
I also experienced the same problem with earlier versions of ReSharper - but since the version 6.1, the problem just disappeared.

Plz tell if it solved your problem, too.

Comment: I hope this is the right way now - plz let me know if not, so that I can learn from it and also improve my answer. I don't remember any more what was the problem with my original answer, which was deleted by a moderator. Thx!

Comment: I'm sorry about this, but I haven't had that same job for almost 2 years. I wouldn't be able to verify if I tried! :D